# Input text validation error - JSP

Tags: java, jsp, validation

I have an input text let's say it's used to input price.
I have validation code on `doinsertproducts.jsp` after the user click submit button on `insertproducts.jsp`

The validation for input price is:

1. the input text must be filled.
2. the input text must be numeric.
3. the price must be greater than zero.

Here's the 1st code:

```
if(price.equals("")||price==null){
    response.sendRedirect("../insertproducts.jsp?insertproduct="+producttype+"&err=Price must be filled.");
    return;
}
else{
        try{
            intprice=Integer.parseInt(price);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            response.sendRedirect("../insertproducts.jsp?insertproduct="+producttype+"&err=Price must be numeric.");
        }
    }
```

And I don't have an idea where did I have to put this second code to check if the input is less than 1:

```
if(intprice<1){
            response.sendRedirect("../insertproducts.jsp?insertproduct="+producttype+"&err=Price must be greater than 0 (zero).");
    }
```

Anyway, when I execute the 1st code and try to input character into the inputtext (without including the 2nd code), there's a root cause error:

```
Cannot call sendRedirect() after the response has been committed
```

Looks like the error hasn't been handled by the code.
Is there any solution so the code could detect 3 errors from the user?

Comment: Side note: `if(price.equals("")||price==null)` - `price == null` is unreachable. Because of `price == null` you'll get NPE. Do `if("".equals(price))`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun still got the error, looks like the problem is the code can't handle character input in the textbox

Comment: You must handle your validation through javascript / jquery on insertproducts.jsp and then on doinsertproducts.jsp just check for null and get parameter.

Comment: @ParkashKumar this is for my assignment. It isn't allowed to use JS/jquery

Comment: Ok so you mean to handle validation on serverside only?

Comment: @ParkashKumar yes indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
String price = request.getParameter("price").toString();
String errorMessage = "";

if(price != null && price != ""){
    try{
        intPrice = Integer.parseInt(price);
        if(intPrice  > 0){
            System.out.println("Price " + intPrice + " is greater to 0.");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Price " + intPrice + " is less then or equal to 0.");
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.getMessage();
        errorMessage = "Price is not a Number.";
        response.sendRedirect("../insertproducts.jsp?insertproduct="+producttype+"&err="+errorMessage);
    }
}else{
   errorMessage = "Price was not given.";
   response.sendRedirect("../insertproducts.jsp?insertproduct="+producttype+"&err="+errorMessage);
}
```

Comment: @noobprogrammer Try above code and ask me, if you find any difficulty.